# Gatling Post ignores Header

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm using Gatling to do some load tests on an application.

Therefore, I have to request a token from a keycloak instance, with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.

```
private val httpRequest = http("Get access token")
    .post("https://********/auth/realms/mds/protocol/openid-connect/token")
    .asFormUrlEncoded
    .formParam("client_id", "********")
    .formParam("client_secret", "********")
    .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")

  val getAccessToken = exec(
    httpRequest
      .check(status.is(200))
      .asJson
      .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
  )
```

The keycloak returns a 415 because of this:

```
=========================
HTTP request:
POST https://********/auth/realms/mds/protocol/openid-connect/token
headers:
    accept: application/json
    host: ********
    content-type: application/json
    content-length: 103
body:FormUrlEncodedRequestBody{contentType='application/json', charset=UTF-8, content=client_id=********&client_secret=********&grant_type=client_credentials}
=========================
```

```
=========================
HTTP response:
status:
    415 Unsupported Media Type
headers:
    ....
body:
{"error":"RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type"}
```

Why is Gatling ignoring my content-type header?

The debugger shows, that the variable `httpRequest` has the correct header. What is changing the header to `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

You're posting formParams that will generate a body encoded with [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), and then you're trying to override the generated associated `content-type` header to `application/json`.

This is non-sensical, resulting in the server not being able to decode the body because the `content-type` doesn't match.

If you want to send JSON, send a JSON payload with a [body](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#full-body), not a form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake after days of search.

the `asJson` does not convert the response to Json, instead it sets a Content-Type and Accecpt `application/json` header

Comment: For future reference: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#asxxx